# Issues with Outlook Room Finder and Automatic Replies, but only when used with a VPN

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vpn, proxy

Wondering if anyone can shed light on this issue..

I am at a client site using Outlook with a VPN which allows me to connect to my own corporate intranet.

With the VPN off everything works swimmingly. With the VPN on I can still send emails etc without any performance impacts. However, I cannot query the availability of rooms or access Automatic Replies. Both will time out.

I'm also using a proxy however the behaviour is the same with it on and off. Regardless I exclude *outlook.domain* traffic from the proxy.

Is it something about the Autodiscover service?

If i ping outlook.domain.com with the VPN on it goes to autodiscover.domain.com, but with the VPN off it goes to the outlook.gslb.domain.com.

I wonder why it redirects to the load balancer only with the VPN off?

Comment: This seems like a local issue specific to your VPN and only your network admin could address the issue. You've described the problem well. Perhaps you should ask the network admin?

Comment: They don't care, just tell me to use the work around. I think the specific fix is not possible, I was just curious what it would be in theory? Because other than those two features Outlook works correctly.

Comment: VPN is supposed to give you the identical environment as if you had your computer at work. In practice though, I have also found that the "identical" environment is not true. You seem to have discovered this as well. I think it is just having limitations in hardware or processes that create differences. Perhaps you can pose a similar question in http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ ... I've ran into similar issues as you have. I'm guessing when I say there's some odd things going with DNS or routing with VPN on. Could also be a sign of laziness, or just a limitation in software/hardwar